# Python List of Dict Logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, continuous-integration

This REPO_SOURCES list of dict from another file. so it define repo name, branch and source_type. So tell me logic so that from source type it check if there github it run GitHubSourceAction otherwise it run CodeCommitSourceAction one.

```
REPO_SOURCES = [
    {"repo": "repo name", "branch": 'master', "source_type": 'github'}
]



pipeline = pipelines.CdkPipeline(self, 'CdkPipeline',
  cloud_assembly_artifact=cloud_assembly_artifact,
  code_pipeline = codepp,
  pipeline_name='Pipeline',
  source_action = [
    cpactions.GitHubSourceAction(
     action_name='GitHub',
     output=source_artifact,
     oauth_token=core.SecretValue.secrets_manager('github-token'),
     owner='OWNER**REPLACEME',
     repo='REPO**REPLACEME',
    trigger=cpactions.GitHubTrigger.POLL
     )
     if source_data["source_type"] == "github"
     else cpactions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
         cpactions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
            repository=codecommit.Repository.from_repository_name(
              self, 
              id="cicd_pipeline",
              repository_name=""
            ),
            branch='master', 
            action_name='CodeCommit',
            trigger=cpactions.CodeCommitTrigger.POLL,
            output=source_artifact,
        ),
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear. The code already checks `source_data["source_type"]` so all you have to do is assign the value(s) of REPO_SOURCES to `source_data`, by iterating over it.